# Change resolution when running in Hyper-V

Tags: display, resolution

What am I missing? I've got Elementary running in Hyper-V, but the only screen resolution available to me is 1152x864.

EDIT:

Of course I figure it out as soon as I post.

For the record, it was adding `video=hyperv_fb:1680x1050` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`, then `update-grub` and a reboot.

Doesn't let me change resolution as and when I want, but should be OK for now.

Comment: Same here. Do you found a Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try install grub-customizer

and change

linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/data-root ro quiet splash **video=hiperv_fb:1920x1080 $vt_handoff**

linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic root=/dev/mapper/data-root ro quiet splash **$vt_handoff video=hiperv_fb:1920x1080**

the problem is **$vt_handoff** you need **video=hiperv_fb:1920x1080** in last part of sentence

Answer (score 0):

Find this:
[Hyper-V with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702628/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution-win-10-15-04)

The script used in this thread is for GNOME.
It's still unclear to me on how to modify this for pantheon, the window manager for Elementary OS.